# Encryption method for using AES-256 symmetric algorithm (AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding) in c#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I want to encrypt a string using AES 256-bit encryption algorithm with ECB and PKCS7Padding. I had gone through many sites but none of them were suitable.
Please suggest a solution

Comment: have you beent there : http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/ ?

Comment: Why would you use ECB mode? It's insecure. Use at least CBC with a random IV instead. The IV doesn't need to be secret, so you can simply prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off before decryption.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string Encrypt(string PlainText, string Password,
               string Salt = "Kosher", string HashAlgorithm = "SHA1",
               int PasswordIterations = 2, string InitialVector = "OFRna73m*aze01xY",
               int KeySize = 256)
           {
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlainText))
                   return "";
               byte[] InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector);
               byte[] SaltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Salt);
               byte[] PlainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText);
               PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);
               byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);
               RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
               SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
               byte[] CipherTextBytes = null;
               using (ICryptoTransform Encryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes))
               {
                   using (MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream())
                   {
                       using (CryptoStream CryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                       {
                           CryptoStream.Write(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);
                           CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                           CipherTextBytes = MemStream.ToArray();
                           MemStream.Close();
                           CryptoStream.Close();
                       }
                   }
               }
               SymmetricKey.Clear();
               return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherTextBytes);
           }
```

[source](http://www.gutgames.com/post/AES-Encryption-in-C.aspx)

Note: you can change the mode by changing  `SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;`

and you can add  `SymmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;` for padding

Answer (score 0):

with [bounty castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) you should be able to do this :

```
cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/ECB/PKCS7"); 
cipher.Init(false, new KeyParameter(key));
```

Comment: what exactly is bounty castle and how to use it, the code should be a standalone code in c#